# Spark Convert Json Array to Struct Array

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for the way to convert the Array of JSON string into Array of struct.

Sample data:

```json
{
  "col1": "col1Value",
  "col2":[
    "{\"SubCol1\":\"ABCD\",\"SubCol2\":\"EFGH\"}",
    "{\"SubCol1\":\"IJKL\",\"SubCol2\":\"MNOP\"}"
  ]
}
```

Dataset schema:

```scala
StructType(StructField(col1,StringType,true), StructField(col2,ArrayType(StringType,true),true))
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
  "col1": "col1Value",
  "col2":[
    {"SubCol1":"ABCD","SubCol2":"EFGH"},
    {"SubCol1":"IJKL","SubCol2":"MNOP"}
  ]
}
```

Expected Schema:

```scala
StructType(StructField(col1,StringType,true), StructField(col2,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(SubCol1,StringType,true), StructField(SubCol2,StringType,true)),true),true))
```

I tried `df.withColumn("col2", from_json($"col2", new_schema))` but this gave me error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'jsontostructs(`col2`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`col2`' is of array type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `col2` to string type first:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("col2", 
    from_json(
        $"col2".cast("string"), 
        lit("array<struct<SubCol1:string, SubCol2:string>>")
        // or use new_schema as in your code
    )
)
```

Comment: `df.withColumn("col2", from_json($"col2".cast("string"), ArrayType(new StructType().add("SubCol1",StringType).add("SubCol2",StringType))))` solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: On the same line, how can we convert the MapType(StringType, StringType) to MapType(StringType, StructType). Here, I want to convert the JSON string Map's value to struct. Casting the column data to String will not work here.